# Real representations of SU(2)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I cannot figure out how to solve this problem.

"*For which irreducibile real representations of SU(2)* $\rho$ , $End(\rho)=\mathbb{R}$? *For Which* $End(\rho)=\mathbb{C}$? *For Which* $End(\rho)=\mathbb{H}$?"

$End(\rho)$ are the endomorphisms of representations, $\mathbb{H}$ is the quaternionic $\mathbb{R}$-algebra.

I know that the irreducible complex representations of SU(2) are $\rho_{m}: SU(2)\rightarrow GL_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathbb{C}[x,y]_m)$, where $\mathbb{C}[x,y]_m$ is the space of the homogeneous polynomial in two variable x,y of degree m.

The only thing I could think about is that if m is even the degree of the representations $\rho_m$ is odd hence they belong to the first type.

Usually with finite groups, I use characters to solve this kind of problem, but I don't know to calculate them for compact groups such as SU(2) (they gave me a formula with an integral, but I cannot apply it).

Comment: Looks like the next step is to figure out the collection of irreducible *real* representations of $SU(2)$, doesn't it? I'm afraid I can't help you with that as the way I have ever studied reps, the difference between real/complex has been of marginal interest only. My guess is that it in this case it revolves around the question of whether a representation factors through $SO(3)$ via the double cover map, but I don't think that's the whole story?

Comment: Just found [this paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82342123.pdf) which addresses exactly that question.